# Parasitic noise after boosting opamp output current

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, current, noise, boost

I'm coming back to you with the same circuit again. I "upgraded" my circuit by turning it into a more powerful one (using a more powerful opamp and adding an output current boost with 2 BJTs).

[image: The circuit]

I'm almost satisfied with this circuit (although i should add more protection because it is high voltage now...). Last problem with it is the fact that i see some "parasitic" noise in the current passing through my capacitor "Cact1" (which is not a capacitor in reality, it is a piezoelectric actuator but electrically the same as a capacitor, which is why i need more current in the real circuit).

[image: Graph]

[image: Graph2]

I see that it happens exactly at the voltage peaks so basically when the current changes direction. This didn't happen when i didn't have the transistors stage wired.

So my guess is that the BJTs are the culprits for this noise and that it happens when the transistors switch in order to make the current change direction. Do you have an idea how this can be fixed ? I really need an almost perfect sine for the current, my application heavily depends on that.

Comment: It looks like classic Class A-B amplifier distortion. Audio amplifiers go to considerable lengths to avoid this. Have a look at their biasing arrangements.

Comment: There's a 10µF cap between opamp IN- and GND so it oscillates.

Comment: Beware of stray coupling to the Vin+. That causes positive feedback during crossover.

Comment: Why does Csens1 have no series R to reduce high frequency gain? Partial gain= \$Aol*2M * \omega Csens1\$

Comment: Before you try to fix anything define all inputs and output V,I BW , sensor noise, leakage, and ground shift (impedance * current (f)).. and why do you need -90V for a unipolar output with a PNP emitter follower will then be a problem

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 "Beware of stray coupling to the Vin+. That causes positive feedback during crossover" What do you mean exactly ? I planning to make that circuit on a PCB, do you mean that the distance between the tracks should be big enough to avoid interferences ?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 "Why do you show an error on schematic with negative bias on Vin+?" What error are you referring to ? I just added an offset to avoid negative values (the actuator Cact1 doesn't like that)

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 "Before you try to fix anything define all inputs and output V,I BW , sensor noise, leakage, and ground shift (impedance * current (f)).. and why do you need -90V for a unipolar output with a PNP emitter follower will then be a problem" I'm a mechanical engineer, that's waaay too hard for me right now to understand.

Comment: Sorry I misread Vcc_  as Vcc- so it is Ok

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 The circuit is based on this small paper https://www.piezodrive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/IntroToCharge.pdf

Comment: Try to define your specs or goals or desired inputs and outputs so as to understand why you have a -Vcc =90V when -5V ought to be enough. What kind of piezo sensor is it?  accelerometer?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 "Try to define your specs or goals or desired inputs and outputs so as to understand why you have a -Vcc =90V when -5V ought to be enough. What kind of piezo sensor is it? accelerometer? "  You are right, -90 volts is not necessary i could do less of course. I actually have all my inputs and outputs already defined : i can generate +-3 volts in the input, but i need the maximum possible swing (only positive). I had to use this opamp because it is the only one going up to 90 volts peak. The problem is that i have to stick to this one opamp configuration (cannot use 2 opamp).

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 It is not a sensor, it's a piezo actuator. I need a good 400 mA to drive it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123412/discussion-between-tony-stewart-ee75-and-af2021).

Comment: 0.4A or 400mA peak seems too high for 750nF+/-10% actuator if Ic= 1uF and let dV=80V and dt = ~1ms for f= 500Hz   and **C=Ic dt/dV** = 0.4 * 1ms / 80V  = 5uF .. Is your assumption wrong about 10uF sensor?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Why are you doing this calculation ? The paper i shared ( piezodrive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/IntroToCharge.pdf ) is saying that the sensing capacitor  Cs is basically the gain of the circuit. So i'm tuning its capacitance value as much as i need output voltage. Did i understand it wrong ?

Comment: Gain is controlled by an impedance ratio. Where did the 10uF come from for a sensor?

Comment: in this link Cp is the actuator, not Cs, yet your schematic shows Cseries ,Cs as Csens rather than Cp parallel

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Maybe i did not explain correctly. The actuator is Cp. The sensing capacitor is Csens1. And that's it. The reason why the 10uF is the sensing capacitor is simply because it shares the same charges as the actuator (since they are in series). The relashionship between input voltage and charges is linear whereas the voltage across the actuator versus input voltage isn't. But this is what the paper says. I personally still don't understand how the actuator is actually DRIVEN in terms of charges. Is it because it is a derivation of the well known integrator opamp ? I don't know...

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 "Gain is controlled by an impedance ratio. Where did the 10uF come from for a sensor?" I just choosed 10uF in order to get a satisfying gain, i didn't think about its capacitance in a sensor view. I mean, i just followed the paper instruction. They say Cs is the charge gain (but also voltage gain if you divide it by the actuator capacitance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you bias the two output BJTs using diodes, for example, you will avoid the cross-over distortion. That is, when the sign of the output signal reverses, one BJT goes off, but the other is not "quick" enough to go on completely. In other words you have their approx. 0.7 V of Vbe to provide above the zero crossing between positive and negative half cycle.

With biasing of the BJT bases (e.g. a 0.7V each give by the voltage drop across two diodes) you will have a bias current flowing "vertically" along the two BJTs (Q2 collector, Q2 emitter, Q1 emitter, Q2 collector). This current can be adjusted ad controlled by putting two small resistors in series with the emitters. Such resistors (named of negative feedback or degeneration) gives you 2 benefits: linearization of the circuit and less variations with temperature.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXfH2k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot ! i didn't know that biasing was a topic for itself. I research on it but for now i get good results with 4 resistors that i randomly choosed and by iteration i found a good fit (no diode for now since i don't know how to select them for a proper biais). I know that i have to provide a voltage as high as the voltage difference between the base and the emitter but how do you select a diode to achieve that ?  That's what i'm working on right now but i'm really discovering all that.

Comment: Also isn't the presence of the diodes in that configuration allowing only one current direction ?

Comment: The center of the diodes is 0V, with +VCC and -VCC at top and bottom of schematic. Now if you apply a small signal vin, e.g. 10mV, and the diodes keep conducting their DC current vertically through 10k resistors, then you shift the voltage values by approx. 10mV. So, +10mV at signal-in, +10mV at the anode of D1, same Q1 BJT, and, assuming the BJT Q1 takes always let's say 0.6V, same at output.

Comment: CONTINUE.  Now you have emitter resistors so that 10mV at output will suffer of some voltage drop across R3 because indeed the current through Q1 increases a bit. [**it is an emitter follower, so you can google for its operating equations]. The same the opposite side, because that +10mV at signal-in shifts also D2, this time away from -VCC , towards positive. So you ed up with Q1 slightly increasing its current and Q2 slightly decreasing it, and output if connected to a load will see a net output current (positive).

Comment: R1 and R2 need to be 2W resistors here. Not a great solution for between 0 to 90V output

Comment: Ok i think i need some time to understand all this in details (i will try to simulate some simple stuff to see clearly what andrea has explained, i might come back to give some news but for now thank you very much all !  (Btw, for the resistors power dissipation, i don't think that it will be a priority to be efficient because i really need precision here, but thanks i didn't paid attention to that)

Comment: @AF2021 Good luck :) Drop a line if you have troubles

Comment: If OP Amp and transistor have sufficient slew rate, it wouldn’t ring at 80kHz approx during transitions. Something else is causing this and the BJT would Have to be rated for 50W or more to drive the expected current x  V drop. This is totally wrong approach. (-1) I suggest 75 V DC bias directly to sensor and 1W audio amp  driver AC coupled to sensor.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Why are you mentionning the 80kHz cutoff frequency ? I only use this circuit upto 1000Hz. Also, i tested this solution and i got rid of this problem. About the power rating of the transistor, i was going to use a heatsink to dissipate the 50W, but indeed it is true that this is not efficient

Comment: 80kHz is the ringing during transition due to differentiation of Csens on the input and wrong values and won’t be accurate

Answer (score 3):

A better current amplifier uses current sensing to compare with the voltage input.

Wires need to be short between sensor and output drivers and back to minimum the area of the inductance loop. Twisted pairs helps that. Coax is better.  Otherwise inductive parasitic oscillations may occur.

The gain of the amplifier is enough excess gain to overcome the Vbe drop without DC bias.

Current sensing is done with a 1 ohm resistor.

DC bias is directly applied with a supply in series with the 750 nF piezo actuator with 90 mohm ESR.  The actuator must be polarized with 150V abs max and without negative voltage.  This is accomplished using 75 Vdc supply and +/-75V for the high voltage Op Amp to provide only the AC current as there is no DC current, just charge bias except during startup.

Each transistor may dissipate up to 5 Watts so a 10W heatsink is needed.

To match the current sense, the input only needs to be +/- 250 mV max so I included a divider for 5Vpp input to 500mVpp just for convenience to use any low-cost low voltage signal gen.

[Here is my design](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCCMB0DsAc9JgEwFYCmBaWIUGZoAWWMNAThUgDZrY0x80Qj8oIiURMtJIAoAO4gmXFEQ74xEqPwBOLKSOrxFXfPmrhZAJRaqU4qFsNFtkbmAgxYZiPehohavDKLkTMlPwDy3Sq4QKgYy9s7uJoj%20YlFg4R4imi4aWnHCNBDoWhmJJvwA5skqyfB24PIsCVmVnvbg0GDkzjkpyUlxAG41ImBmEbnaHBD0g-VOwv2tFOrt-AAO0XhR0wMWYRNVUZO9ssLwmUY5pnj8AIbGmV6w0hDkICM4zMhWLyBYYNCQRGiwkKRENDQfB%20YC070%20RGoX2%208HwREQP3IuGeLwqKGugR6ZnEdRRznRXD%20JgxOJOABcsXgjKIqWULLwaNB8I1yEjKORIB58PSPtcAfAUOygQCqNkrCAACYYABmpwArgAbMn8CnM7FoLQ06oQXiJaDUcgvFBgUj7TTwMG88SQAVCr6QUXsCBS2WK5XCNW0ymktLemSe7X8PRasCqGlE0YyEZ1D5OYNoMQYmmeuoyR6jWPxWqLH38Y13frVQuxe6ObC4OGOa6sqTkAHUblsCwCQp8MQaqAOvAYsIKI4dtt4DvWVESNj4UqdrhAwnUXHkAD6WQXsAXXxS1AXHxekC3DSsu7Aa7X1H1nMNsFgdAbsLo-DHIknEZnXsyR%20Xq-Xmk324Pe53W7HoywR-ECXLkE4CisDcbSpE6qIKPsXqDtq8EVEhxzwq%20ICGlY96MG8OQRlgSg%20ngC4zoBDpoJCa5wPgrKMeQSAir0RD-n%2075Lgu%20ALgAagAlgAdgAOgAzuJYkAManAqGASuJAD0yD4U2V5TpSEbWPAFEOlR6C0bY0ClD8SCUMgh77mAu4oNxNo8ap3BzlAKCqMEUABBwS4alRrBQjpRlfECCYaoKzK2b%201l2fx4kAPZysqsV4NkrnmH5NpQO40CinW4jUDRjC4JFax4MlIj8El1ipU2BnMMV9R-AC3yGmgiCoFYrDaFwdQAJJxQl-ATqVdRcOJYDiWSsXiSgfFzOJAC2pwAB6DQYIiWJYEAAGJyBgACOcoYEJUkAJ78EAA)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tony it looks amazing ! i played with it a bit but seems like it is frequency dependant : if i use a voltage peak of 1.4 V for example with a frequency of 113Hz, the voltage output saturate. Do you see the same thing ?

Comment: This is a constant  peak current (charge rate) amplifier controlled by output current feedback, so voltage increases with lower frequency and that means you are limited in displacement and current at lower frequencies.

Comment: Then i guess the gain is not constant. This is a problem. The actuator needs to be driven from 50Hz to 1000Hz. It is not going to be usable in a dynamic manner.